# Textblock not appearing in pivot

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a pivot Item a with a colored background on the header,

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
  <Rectangle
    VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    Height="150" Fill="Red" />

  <phone:Pivot >
    <phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize=" 25" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>

    <phone:PivotItem Header="item1">
      <TextBlock Text="Test" />
    </phone:PivotItem>
    <phone:PivotItem Header="item2">
      <Grid/>
    </phone:PivotItem>
  </phone:Pivot>
</Grid>
```

The problem is that the TextBlock only appears on the Red Background but I would like that that red Backround only contains the Header Title.

How can I make the Textblock appear below the red Background?

EDIT :

Here is a picture to show my problem :
[image]

I would like this "Test"  text to be below that red background, I would like that background to only cover my titles "element1" and "element2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="89" Fill="Red" />

    <phone:Pivot >
        <phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize=" 25" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>

        <phone:PivotItem Header="item1"  Margin="10,51,14,32">
            <TextBlock Text="Hello World! &#10;This is a test for item1" Height="640" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
        </phone:PivotItem>
        <phone:PivotItem Header="item2"  Margin="10,51,14,32">
            <TextBlock Text="Hello World! &#10;This is another test for item2" Height="640" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
        </phone:PivotItem>
    </phone:Pivot>
</Grid>
```

I have tested this.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one it would work

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
            <!--Pivot Control-->
            <controls:Pivot Title="MY APPLICATION">
                <!--Pivot item one-->
                <controls:PivotItem  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="485" Padding="0" Name="pivotitemRecorder">
                    <controls:PivotItem.Header >
                        <Border Margin="-10,20,0,0" Height="70" Width="160" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="#FF9666D1"  CornerRadius="10" Background="Green">
                            <Border Width="150" Height="50" Backgroung="Red">
                                <TextBlock Margin="0,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="First" Foreground="White"  FontSize="36" FontWeight="Bold"  />
                            </Border>

                        </Border>
                    </controls:PivotItem.Header>
                </controls:PivotItem>
            </controls:Pivot>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: It's not working, I have "Header can not be found in PivotItem type" and "HeaderTemplate" can not be empty

Comment: i will give you other solution

Comment: it's almost it i added another Pivot Item exactly like the one you gave but i would the red background to cover all of the rectangle , without any blank between the Item Headers if you see what i mean

Comment: if u don't need any blank between that then you could set margin like this Margin="-10,0,0,0" of pivot item control and height and width accordingly

Comment: I did :  <Border Margin="-10,0,0,0" Height="70" Width="400" [ect]>  but the problem is that then the size of the header changes I want the size of the header to be the same what i just want is a recantgle background for my headers

Comment: put your textblock inside other border and give its height width and margin accordingly

Comment: sorry but i don't see what you mean can you edit you code please

Comment: i still have a blank between the headers, i added a picture on my post to show my problem